# How to assign object to output of a function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to assign something to the output of Sys.Date(). For example, say I want to name the object with today's date:

`format(Sys.Date(), "%b%d") <- mtcars`

I get the error:
invalid (NULL) left side of assignment.

I tried:
`eval(parse(text = format(Sys.Date(), "%b%d"))) <- mtcars`

Gets the same error msg. What am I missing /  is there a solution?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Having data stored in the variable name itself is usually a bad idea in R. It would be better if you need to generate names dynamically to use a named list and avoid the `eval()` and `assign()` functions because they create unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I'm basically timestamping dataframes that I'm working on -  I name them manually now which gets tedious the more what-ifs I want to run. I can see the value of holding them in a list, less clutter for one, but how would I add a new element to a dynamically named slot in the list? I have list x with elements Sep03 and Sep09 - how would I add a dynamically named element Sep11 to x?

Comment: You can assign with any string value like `x[["Sep11"]] <- mtcars` or a function that returns a string value `x[[format(Sys.Date(), "%b%d")]] <- mtcars`. Then you'll have all the values nicely stored in `x` and you can get at them with `x[["Sep11"]]` or `x$Sep11` or even apply a function to each element in the list.

Comment: @MrFlick Assigning to function output in a named list worked and I see myself using it. My question was about assigning in the global environment however, so I will leave akrun's as the accepted answer. Hive it off as a separate answer for other people to find? Guessing SO will weight answers over comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `assign`

```
assign(format(Sys.Date(), "%b%d"), mtcars)

head(Sep11)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Thank you! I did try assign first but simply wrapped format() in it and got the same error.